# How to use 'find' and 'cpio' to exclude parent directories

Tags: linux, find, cp, cpio

I want to copy over all html files in a nested directory but I want to prevent the parent folders above it from being generated as well.

That is if my source path is 
`/project/ng1/src/templates/**`, I would like my generated folders to just be `/templates/**`.

I currently have the following command:

```
find projects/ng1/src/templates -name '*.html' -path pages | cpio -pdm projects/ng7/templates
```

But this generates the folder structure: `projects/ng7/templates/project/ng1/templates/**`

I would like: `projects/ng7/templates/**`

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Put this line into your `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile`, adjust the path as needed.

```
export PROJECTS=/path/to/my/projects
```

Then open a new terminal.

```
$ cd $PROJECTS/ng1/src/templates
$ find . -name '*.html' -path pages | cpio -pdm $PROJECTS/ng7/templates
```